# Is there an equivalent to ESLL in ANSYS ACT?

Tags: python-2.7, ansys

I'm looking for an ACT command that selects all elements that are connected to a line. In MAPDL this command was called ESLL.
Currently my script, which saves the elements in a named selection, looks kind of clunky:

```
geo_body = geo_data.GeoEntityById (line_body) # Get geoEdgeWrapper id
tree_body = tree_geometrie.GetBody (geo_body) # get connected body in tree
sel.Ids = [geo_body.Id] # construct selection from id
## Results
namedSel = ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.NamedSelections.AddNamedSelection ()
namedSel.Name = tree_body.Name + '_elements'
namedSel.ScopingMethod = GeometryDefineByType.Worksheet
namedSel.GenerationCriteria.Add (None)
namedSel.GenerationCriteria [0] .EntityType = SelectionType.GeoBody
namedSel.GenerationCriteria [0] .Criterion = SelectionCriterionType.Name
namedSel.GenerationCriteria [0] .Operator = SelectionOperatorType.Equal
namedSel.GenerationCriteria [0] .Value = tree_body.Name
namedSel.GenerationCriteria.Add (None)
namedSel.GenerationCriteria [1] .Action = SelectionActionType.Convert
namedSel.GenerationCriteria [1] .EntityType = SelectionType.MeshElement
namedSel.Generate ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually retrieve mesh data directly from geometric entities (using the Id). From your script, considering that you know the Id of your line body as 'line_body' var, you can do:

```
# Get access to mesh data:
meshGroup = ExtAPI.DataModel.MeshDataByName('Global')
mesh_line = meshGroup.MeshRegionById(line_body)
elem_line = mesh_line.Elements
```

This will return list of element objects associated to the line body.

Note that you can check name of meshes available in:

```
meshGroup = ExtAPI.DataModel.MeshDataNames
```